# Minecraft * Line 1, Column 2 Missing ‘}’ or object member name error

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I Typed In The Chat

```
/give @s skull 1 3 {SkullOwner:”TBNRfrags”}
```

And It Said

> * Line 1, Column 2 Missing ‘}’ or object member name

in red. I Tried It Again In A Command block, and the same thing happened. I Played In Minecraft PE, BTW. Not Java. And TBNRfrags is one of my favorite YouTubers.

Comment: It's not a JSON error. The command just simply cannot be used in MCPE.

Answer (score 0):

You can only get custom player skulls in Java edition and a player with a head you want would have to be in the game. So if you wanted TBNRfrags skull you would need a player with his skin in Java edition and in the command you'd need to replace TBNRfrags with the players name.